# How to get only the last element of the large dataset in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I am using the dataset api to create a dataset of List of string and I need to extract only the last list  from the dataset which has list of strings.Is it possible to get only the last element from the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that you are in a parallel execution environment. If you want to have a "last entry", you basically have to serialize your computation (like `mapPartition().setParallelism(1)`).

But you should first explain what your order is. If there is an order in your `DataSet`, you can simply pairwise `reduce()` your result. This would be parallelizable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you have mentioned my dataset is DataSet<List<String>>. So it will have lots of List<Strings> and I have to extract the last List<String> not the last string in a list.Is there any way to do it

Comment: Sorry, I got your question wrong. I updated my answer.

Comment: As per my requirement I created a list which will have string objects and I read a file of huge size and  updating the  list by performing some operations over each data got from file on the data in List. Now when each data I read from file I create a list<String> in map function adn sending to dataset.So finally I need to extract only the last List<String> from the dataSet

Comment: List<String> ethOrderBook = new ArrayList<String>();
 DataSet<List<String>> dataSet = sortedRawData.map(new MapFunction<String, List<String>>() {
 public List<String> map(String rawOrderData) throws Exception {
    ................................
    some operations withs the string rawOrderData received..............
    List<String> ethBook = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (OrderData orderData : ethOrderBook) {
       ethBook.add(orderData.toString());
      }
       
      return ethBook;
    }
    });

Comment: I think the easiest solution for you is my first approach. Create a mapPartition(), set the parallelism to one such that all lists end up at one place and check if the hasNext() in the function is false. If so, this is the last element.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.I have used mapPartition() and now able to get the last List<String>()